# Unknown parameter validation in @RequestBody in spring 4

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring rest service like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/is"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ISResponce> createService(@RequestBody Service service)
{
    .................
}
```

Request body is like ::

```
{
  "customer" : {
    "extUserFullName" : "9999abcdefgh",
    "extUserName" : "999999abcdefgh",
    "extUserPassword" : "qwe"

  },

  "service" : {
    "ol" : 400,
    "sTag" : 512,
    "cTag" : 3333,
    "packageID" : "ABCDE",
    "custType" : "",
    "custSegmentation" : ""
  }
}
```

When I gave some unknown(extra) parameter "**test**" in request it is accepting. But I want to throw exception in the below scenario.

```
{
  "customer" : {
    "extUserFullName" : "9999abcdefgh",
    "extUserName" : "999999abcdefgh",
    "extUserPassword" : "qwe"

  },

  "service" : {
    "ol" : 400,
    "test": "test",
    "svTag" : 512,
    "cvTag" : 3333,
    "packageID" : "ABCDE",
    "custType" : "",
    "custSegmentation" : ""
  }
}
```

spring.xml looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:com/netcracker/platform/beans/configuration/dob-beans.xml"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>      
          <bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="configure" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value type="org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature">FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES</value>
            <value>true</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation‌​.RequestMappingHandl‌​erAdapter"> 
    <property name="messageConverters"> 
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
            </bean>
        </list> 
    </property> 
</bean> 

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver"/>

    <bean class="com.netcracker.solutions.etisalat.rvcpe.so.rest.responses.RequiredIfFieldMatchValidator"/>

</beans>
```

and pom.xml is

```
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>apache</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>snmp4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netcracker.spring-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-commons-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>apache</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-vfs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance-repackaged</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jradius</groupId>
            <artifactId>jradius-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>apache</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
            <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbcdriver</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>apache</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-commons</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Someone, please help me. Thanks in advance ) !!!

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` in your configuration file.

Here is an example of java configuration which overrides all the default json deserializer and your application should throw exception on unknown properties.

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true)
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
    return converter;
}
```

below should be the XML equivalent.

```
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="configure" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value type="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature">FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES</value>
            <value>true</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi Avinash,Thank you so much for your prompt response. Above code, where exactly I should write, I mean in POJO or in controller class

Comment: you need to write it in your java configuration class.

Comment: I don't have a configuration class, I have a spring xml like this..\n`<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
         <property name="messageConverters">
                 <list>
                         <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
                 </list>
         </property>
 </bean>
  <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />`\n Can you please tell me, how to configure in xml

Comment: Hi Avinash, I tried your configuration and I am getting below exception during deployment time. Please find above updated spring.xml and pom.xml

Comment: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation‌​.RequestMappingHandl‌​erAdapter] ; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation‌​.RequestMappingHandl‌​erAdapter`

Comment: what is the version of Spring you are using, show us the parent pom, this pom doesn't have any version.

Comment: I am using 4.2.4.RELEASE version

Comment: `Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean#0' defined in VFS resource : Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig$Feature, java.lang.String)`

Comment: Also I feel `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` should be updated to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`. Let me know please

Comment: after updating to this, i got this exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation‌​.RequestMappingHandl‌​erAdapter`

Comment: use MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter instead of Requ‌​estMappingHandl‌​erA‌​dapter, updated the answer.

Comment: this time deployment is success, but when I pass extra parameter in request, it is accepting, where it should not accept. I tried by changing spring version to 4.0.1.RELEASE, then it is rejected. Why this is not working in 4.2.4.RELEASE ??. Could you please help me where I am wrong